# Computed resValue from buildType and flavor

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-productflavors

My application is composed of three build types: dev, stage and release. And two flavors: p2p and pro.

In build.gradle I use resValue to define, for each build type, the scheme to use:

- custom_url_dev
- custom_url_stage
- custom_url_prod

I would like also to configure the scheme by flavor. Something like:

- custom_url_pro_dev
- custom_url_p2p_dev
- custom_url_pro_stage
- custom_url_p2p_stage
- custom_url_pro_prod
- custom_url_p2p_prod

So basically, I need to compute a resValue from the current build type and the current flavor. Is this possible with Gradle? Or is there a better way to get this result?

Answer (score 0):

It will be more cumbersome, but I think you'll need type+flavor-specific resource files, and you'll customize in each individual file. Your directory structure will look something like this:

```
src
    main
    p2pDev
        res
            values
                strings.xml
    proDev
        res
            values
                strings.xml
    p2pStage
        res
            values
                strings.xml

...
```